# Copy data between DB tables with different schema using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I've 2 tables A, B in MySql DB.

Table A has 2 columns (user, pass)

Table B has additional 3 columns (user, pass, date1, date2, boolean)

I want to copy data from table A and insert it to table B with default values for additional columns.
What is the best way to achieve this? (sql is preferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this url

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html
```

they have also posted an example below exactly like your requirement in the discussion section

```
mysql> INSERT INTO orders (customer_cust_id, orderdatetime, message, taxrate, shippingprice)
    -> SELECT '1', NOW(), null, taxrate, shippingprice FROM customer
    -> WHERE cust_id='1';
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

hope this helps

Comment: It had worked. 
The only drawback is that I've auto_increment column on table B and after this query it was incremented twice as much as it needed. any ideas?

Comment: added the auto increment column to the above query - didn't work

Comment: can you give the exact query that you are using?? I can check in that

Comment: Here you go :

INSERT INTO Users (userId, username,password,activated,payingStatus,createTime,updateTime) 
   SELECT  NULL, username, password, TRUE, 0, NOW(), NOW() from users

Comment: ok....remove the userId field and also remove the NULL , as it is autoincrement(and NOT NULL), it will automatically do entry in that attribute

Comment: yes, I've added them per your suggesstion. removing them will also double increment the count

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10120/discussion-between-sandeep-rajoria-and-eldad-levy)

Answer (score 1):

if the defaults are undefined in the table:

```
insert into b (user,pass,date1,date2,boolean) 
select user,pass,'2012-04012','2012-04012',true from a
```

if the table definition includes defaults:

```
insert into b (user,pass,date1,date2,boolean) 
select user,pass from a
```

Answer (score 0):

This insert statement uses a select clause to provide the values for the insert:

```
insert into B(user,pass) select user,pass from A;
```